I want to know the name of an old WB animated short
This has bugged me for years, as I could never think of the title and I've never seen it on one of those Looney Tunes collections: 
There is an old Warner Brothers cartoon (my guess is it's from the late 50s or early 60s) when a bulldog or a sheepdog (can't remember) with a strong Brooklyn accent is trying to teach a fox how to become a watchdog.  The fox became the protagonist because he told the dog that he wasn't really a fox; he was a dog interested in learning the master's tricks.  The dog sees through this, and accordingly runs him through the ringer, concluding each bit with a "lesson," i.e. "that's lesson 2 - never let them..." right after he's dropped an anvil on his head or something like that.  
Does anybody know the name of the short that I am talking about?

The correct short is actually A Fox in a Fix, one of the Merrie Melodies series, directed by Robert McKimson (creator of Foghorn Leghorn and Speedy Gonzales among others). It can be found on YouTube here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pFAdJPYmNk

I just watched it for the first time in about 20 years...it's still funny! Thanks!

Actually, I think I found it:
http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/A_Fox_in_a_Fix

I was just getting ready to post that. It's on YouTube but you sign in to view it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pFAdJPYmNk

Thanks, the youtube is particularly helpful; post this as an answer and I will mark it as such.
